# class method overloading with generic in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I don't know  how to write the method overloading，
see the code below,
the method `emit` requires numbers of params, depends on the first params `evt` and generic T，
if T[evt] was a none params function, `emit` needs only one param，
if T[evt] had some params， the second param of `emit` should be a array, and it's type show matches `Parameters<T[evt]>`

```
interface IEventListeners {
  [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => void | false
}

export class EventEmiiter<
  T extends IEventListeners
>  {
  private _listeners: {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K][]
  } = {};

  public on<E extends keyof T>(evt: E, executor: T[E]) {
    const listener = this.getListener(evt);
    listener.push(executor);
    return () => {
      this.off(evt, executor);
    }
  }

  public off<E extends keyof T>(evt: E, executor: T[E]) {
    const listener = this.getListener(evt);
    const index = listener.findIndex(exe => exe === executor);
    listener.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public emit<E extends keyof T>(evt: E, params?: Parameters<T[E]>)  {
    const listener = this.getListener(evt);
    const iter = listener[Symbol.iterator]();
    let iterObj: ReturnType<typeof iter['next']>;
    let falseValue: undefined | false;
    while (iterObj = iter.next()) {
      const result = iterObj.value(...(params || []))
      if (result === false) {
        falseValue = false;
      }
      if (iterObj.done) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return falseValue;
  }

  private getListener<E extends keyof T>(evt: E) {
    return this._listeners[evt] = this._listeners[evt] || [];
  }

  /** 
   * React Component Hook 
   * @describe 用于订阅的hooks, 不需考虑事件的卸载， 组件卸载时自动卸载事件 
   * */
  public useSubscribe<E extends keyof T>(evt: E, executor: T[E]) {
    const off = this.on(evt, executor);
    
    useUnmount(() => {
      off();
    })

    return off;
  }
}


type Subscribers = {
  onOk: () => void;
  onClick: (val: number) => void;
}
const emitter = new EventEmiiter<Subscribers>;

emitter.emit('onOk') // expect an error since (val: number) => void requires one param.
emitter.emit('onClick');
```

I wanner write some code like this

```
class EventEmitter {
  public emit<E extends keyof T>(evt: E)
  public emit<E extends keyof T>(evt: E, params: Parameters<T[E]>)
  public emit<E extends keyof T>(evt: E, params?: Parameters<T[E]>)
}
```

i expects this declare can throw the error be expexted to get, but it also can't.

So , what is the right way to write ?

Comment: `evt: E, ...params: Parameters<T[E]>` ?

Comment: Thanks, it works! I can take it. But i wonder how to write if the second param "params" is an array.

Comment: why iter and not `for-of`?

Comment: ...
Just go find some proper ts EventEmitter impl on npm